Fixed point vs Float point number
I have a project that is basically to analyze the effects of quantization on orientation estimation algorithms. I have sensor data from gyroscope that looks like this when using float datatype:
gx=-0.001064650843716541
gy=-0.0042603487041181585
gz=0.0053267448770866945

When i use "sc_fixed < 16,8,SC_TRN,SC_SAT >" dedicating 8 bits to the integar part and remaining bits to the fractional part, i get the following results,
gx=-.00390625
gy=-.0078125
gz=.00390625

I am just failing to understand how does quantization worsen these values. I have tried to used the following bit configurations:
"sc_fixed < 24,10,SC_TRN,SC_SAT >"
"sc_fixed < 32,10,SC_TRN,SC_SAT >"
"sc_fixed < 32,11,SC_TRN,SC_SAT >"

The results are effected but now as much when i use < 16,8 >

You probably don't want fixed point.  You certainly don't want fixed point with just 8 bits for the fractional part.  With 8 bits for the fractional part, you get a resolution of 1/256, or 0.00390625.  So you can represent the numbers 0, 0.00390625, 0.0078125, 0.01171875, ..., but nothing in between.  Your gx, gy, and gz numbers are very small, so it's not surprising they got "rounded off" (worsened) badly when coerced into being multiples of 1/256.

It looks like your numbers are all comfortably less than 0.01.  Even a fixed-point format that devoted all of its bits to the fraction (none to the integer) would still waste a lot of resolution for these numbers.  I'd say you want to use something like 16 bits, with -6 of them for the integer, and the other 22 for the fraction.  That'd let you represent numbers from 0 to 0.015625, with a resolution of about 0.0000002.  (But, yes, I'm sort of kidding about the -6 bits for the integer. :-) )

Bottom line, if you're bound and determined to use fixed point, it looks like you want to devote as many bits as you can to the fraction, with few or none devoted to the integer.

Thank you for your response Steve. It was very helpless. Is there a way to find out what would be the minimum number of bits to represent those values without rounding error?

I like your sense of humor :') I actually cant dedicate very less bits to the integar part since these values would serve as an input for the orientation estimation algorithms like Madgwick, Mahony and im supposed to use fixed point datatype across all operations

You're probably always going to have "rounding error".  But the math for how much you'll get is simple.  If you're using binary fixed point (as it looks like you are here), then if you have N bits allocated to the fraction, you'll have a resolution of 2^(-N).  If you want M (decimal) digits of precision, you'll need about log₂(10^M) fraction bits to achieve it.

Re “I am just failing to understand how does quantization worsen these values”: There are two problems. One, you have shown us two different sets of numbers. The first gx, gy, and gz do not appear to be related to the second gx, gy, and gz. If we round the first gx, gy, and gz to the Q16.8 format, we do not get the second gx, gy, and gz. E.g., for gy, −0.0042603487041181585, would convert, with rounding to nearest, to −.00390625, not −.0078125. So it is not clear how you are determining these numbers are worse when they appear to be from a different sample.

Two, how could the numbers not get worse? −.00390625 is −1/256, and that is the smallest a number can be in the Q16.8 format without becoming zero. The two nearest representable numbers are 0 and −.0078125. Those are the only choices in Q16.8; you cannot have −0.001064650843716541 or −0.0042603487041181585. In that area, you have to pick 0, −.00390625, or −.0078125.

Re “The results are effected but now as much when i use < 16,8 >”: Yes, formats with more bits for the fraction part can represent the numbers more finely and therefore have less rounding error. That seems like it should not be surprising.
